# RabbitMQ to BlockingQueue binding

Tags: java, queue, rabbitmq, messaging, spring-amqp

I am developing a multithreaded application, where several "processors" (Runnables in ThreadPools) send messages to each other. They communicate using `BlockingQueue` interface: when processor `A` is done with task `T1`, it pushes it to queue `Q1` (for example, `BlockingQueue<MyTask>` if `T1` is represented by class `MyTask`); after that, processor `B` pulls task from `Q1`, performs computations and pushes result result in `Q2`; and so on.

I use `LinkedBlockingQueue`, because my application is monolithic and all processors "live" in the same JVM. However, I want my application to become modular ([Microservice Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html)), so I decided to use RabbitMQ as a message broker.

The problem is to migrate from java implementations of the queues to RabbitMQ with minimal changes in client's source code. Thereby, I try to find some kind of binding between RabbitMQ abstractions and `BlockingQueue` interface. So, when somebody sends a message to amqp's queue, it should appear in a java queue. And vice versa: when somebody pushes an object to the java queue, it should be propagated to an amqp's exchange.

An example implementation of the polling (from amqp's queue, using [spring-amqp](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/)) is presented below.

```
<T> BlockingQueue<T> createQueue(Class<T> elementType, MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer) {
    LinkedBlockingQueue<T> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    MessageConverter messageConverter = listenerContainer.getMessageConverter();
    listenerContainer.setupMessageListener((MessageListener) message -> {
        Object task = messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
        queue.offer(elementType.cast(task));
    });

    return queue;
}
```

I cannot find a framework that implements `BlockingQueue` interface using RabbitMQ's queues by now. If that kind of framework doesn't exist, is my idea architecturally wrong in some way, or just nobody have not implemented this yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you really want to do it the way you describe - the inbound messages will be delivered to the queue and sit in memory, not in RabbitMQ.

I think a simple `BlockingQueue` implementation that uses a `RabbitTemplate` underneath to pull messages from the rabbit queue (using `receive()`, or `receiveAndConvert()`) might be better for take/poll operations - it will leave the message in RabbitMQ until needed, and simply `RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend()` for offer/put operations.

While pretty simple, it might be a useful addition to the framework; consider [contributing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/README.md#contributing-to-spring-amqp).

Comment: In addition to Gary's answer I suggest to take a look to the Spring Integration Framework which provides the `PollableAmqpChannel`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-channels

Comment: Gary, thank you for your answer. Actually, I meant that kind of implementation, but I thought that it already exists. I'll consider contributing after integration this implementation in my project (if spring-integration won't work in my case).

Comment: @ArtemBilan thank you, I'll try spring-integration. First impression is quite positive.

Comment: Gary, recently I realised absence of blocking semantics of `receive()`. As I can see, [you suggest](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-401) bypassing spring-amqp and use rabbit client directly for achieving blocking behaviour (extending [Consumer](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.3.4/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.3.4/com/rabbitmq/client/Consumer.html))?

Comment: Blocking `receive()` was added in the [recent 1.5 release](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/_introduction.html#_rabbittemplate_changes). Thanks for pointing out that JIRA issue; it was replaced by [this one](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-503).